# How to enable filtering on a field defined by DLOOKUP()?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a form `TForm` based on table `T`, set up as a datasheet.  My goal is to add a filterable column to the datasheet where the column's value is calculated from a query using  another column's value.

I tried to do this by adding a text box `currentBox` to `T`.  The control source for `currentBox` is:

```
=DLookUp("name","currentStatus","itemID=" & [ID])
```

where `[ID]` is a field in `T` and `currentStatus` is an aggregate query on a table that `T` is related to.

I can filter on all the fields in `TForm` that are in `T`.  But I can't filter on `currentBox`, even though it also appears as a column in the form; clicking on the column header doesn't do anything.

I'm guessing the problem is that `currentBox` is not bound to a field in `T`; is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Can you make `currentStatus` a calculated field in the form's recordsource query?

Comment: The form's recordsource is table `T`, not a query.  Maybe I could change the recordsource to a join query that would include all the `T` fields as well as `currentStatus`, but then wouldn't I lose the ability to modify the contents of `T` using the form?

Comment: @HansUp, Just tried this, and it does give me a filterable version of `currentStatus`, but as predicted, `T` data can no longer be modified from `TForm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that I ended up solving this was to add a field to `T`, and have that field updated during the `AfterUpdate()` event with the value from the `DLookup()` call.  Because the field is now no longer query-based, it can be used to filter the form.

Comment: This would have been my next suggestion if my first wasn't workable in your system.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a VBA solution:

1. Add a combo box (aka drop-down) object to your form header.  This drop-down's source will be an independent query that displays all the values your Dlookup() currently pulls (names?) and stores the itemID. Let's call it `ObjPickName` in this example.
2. Add an `AfterUpdate` event to `ObjPickName` that will filter your form for you (your form will still be based on `T`).  The code will be something like:

   `Private Sub Combo_ObjPickName_AfterUpdate()

       Me.Form.Filter="[itemID]='" & Me.Combo_ObjPickName.Value & "'"

       Me.Form.Filteron=True

   End Sub`