# Follow -up ... how to enable filtering on a field defined by DLOOKUP()?

Tags: ms-access

I am looking at the following post [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576613/how-to-enable-filtering-on-a-field-defined-by-dlookup) and am struggling with how to perform the answer to the question:

> The way that I ended up solving this was to add a field to T, and have that field updated during the AfterUpdate() event with the value from the DLookup() call. Because the field is now no longer query-based, it can be used to filter the form.

Specifically, what are the steps to update the 'table field' with the value from the DLookup() call? Do I place the DLookup in VB code?

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer using vb codes but that is because I don't feel as flexible in the things I want to accomplish using macros. However, if you don't want to use VB code you can create a bound text box that captures the value of the unbound DLookup. then have the bound text box set to `visible = false`. that way you will not have two box with the same information on your form.

Comment: thanks for the response; do you mind providing some code that would show how to 'capture the value' of the unbound DLookup? my DLookup is providing a unique value for each record as follows: '=DLookUp("Title","t_01_0_Departments","ID = " & [Department1ID])'

Comment: You can use the INSERT INTO to put the value into the table. Here is an answer by Seth Schrock (http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/947607-how-save-value-unbound-text-boxes-field-table) but an even easier way I use is the append query in MS Access that requires just 2 to 3 lines of coding. see this video - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eiu8UTAvbrM let me know how it turned out